# UITableView in UInavigationController not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

[image]I have been searching and experimenting on this for a while, but I just can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

I want to make an app with a menu, and from that menu, you can get to a `TableViewcontroller` with a title bar. I found out that, in order to get this title bar, you need to "insert" `UITableViewController` into a `UINavigationController`. this is where I'm stuck.

let's not mind / forget the menu from the app for now, because i know how to switch view controllers when user taps a button.

in my AppDelegate.m I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    TableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableView];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

in my AppDelegate.h file I Have:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    UINavigationController *navcontroller;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

I have 2 classer, `UITableViewController` and NavigationView.

In the `UITableViewController`, I made an array called `tableRows`:

```
tableRows = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil] init];
```

the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is set as 1 and the `numberOfRowsInSection` is set as `return tableRows.count;`

I left my NavigationView.m untouched, except that I tried to set a title in it.

in my `NavigationView.xib`, I tried to make the connection between the `UITableViewController` and the `UINavigationController`.

- I added an NSObject, and changed its class to AppDelegate
- I replaced the View for a `UIWindow` and connected the window property from my
  `AppDelegate.h` to it
- I added a `UINavigationController` and
  connected it with the `navController` from my `AppDelegate.h`.
- and last, I changed the class from the RootView from the
  `UINavigationController` to `UITableViewController`.

Now my problem is, with or without the connections in IB, whatever I try to change in my table, or in the titlebar, it does not change when I run the app.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using xcode 4.6, so lots of the tutorials I've checked are not very useful, because they are made with older versions of xcode. please help me, Thank you in advance!

Comment: If possible take another ViewController with XIB and add tableView inside ViewController. It may possible you cant directly add that tableView.

Comment: infortunately not possible. When I do this, it also gives an issue: `loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.';`

Comment: its not not loading data right?

Comment: are you there @JorisDijkstra, reply please

Comment: probably not no. i'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong, because when I start searching other questions on SO and other sites, this seems to be the most simple thing out there. after dealing with this for a while without any result it starts running me desperate..

Comment: i'm probably doing something wrong in the connection between the navcontroller and the table controller, but i cannot find out what.

Comment: Please try to set ViewController's view with default view outlet in XIB.

Comment: @Nirav could you explain this a little bit more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]in you `AppDelegate` replace this line

```
    TableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

with this

```
    TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: i found solution for it. check this out, you are initialising UITableViewController instead your TableViewController class.

Comment: yes, this does change anything, but I probably have to do something with outlets, because it says  `'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "TableViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

Comment: exactely, now assign outlet to your tableview

Comment: now this is a problem. Could you describe this process to me? I never did this before because programming is a new thing to me. I really appreciate your effort so far!

Comment: i have attached a screenshot for that, dont forget to assign delegate and datasource as shown, @JorisDijkstra let me know the insights?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27271/discussion-between-dipen-panchasara-and-joris-dijkstra)

Comment: Thank you so much! you helped me out of a great struggle.

Comment: hello @JorisDijkstra come int chat room

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating an instance of `TableViewController` but instead `UITableViewController` so thus you're not getting any of your code executed. (You should have a compiler warning for this in your app delegate - make sure to heed those warnings). Likewise you're not loading the NavigationView nib anywhere - you're creating a navigation controller with the table as the root view controller. It's not clear what your objective for NavigationView is so I can't provide a recommendation for how to proceed. However, for the table view, change the following line in your app delegate

```
TableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

to

```
TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
```

In your table view xib, make sure File's Owner's class is set to be of class `TableViewController` (not `UITableViewController`). Right click on the table view and drag the circles next to 'data source' and 'delegate' to file's owner. Then right click file's owner and make sure the circle next to 'view' is connected to the table view. Save, clean, and run.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find it very useful to checkout the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework will take your array and automatically generate all the table view cells, while managing all the details required to correctly setup the navigation controller. Hope this helps.